# copy files from one folder to another folder using R and a csv file listing filenames to copy

Tags: r, csv, copy

I would like to use a csv file which lists the filenames I want copied from one folder to another. The 'from' folder contains some files I do NOT want copied, in addition to the files I do want copied. I have a csv file containing a list of filenames I want copied. Each file consists of multiple extensions (.sid, .xml, etc.) and I want all components of the file copied. I have no problem using a library such as `stringr` to help accomplish the task.

Does someone have a slick function already written to handle this task?

Here is the beginning of the script I have...

```
> library (stringr)
> 
> copy_from <- "c:/Temp/test/copy_from/"
> copy_to <- "c:/Temp/test/copy_to/"
> index <- read.csv ("c:/Temp/test/index.csv",header=T)
> index$filename <- as.character(index$filename) #need to convert field to character for susbstr to work
> index$name <- substr(index$filename,1,nchar(index$filename)-4) #now I have a new column with only the filename and not the extension
> index
             filename            name
1   voya_20140721.SID   voya_20140721
2   voya_20140801.SID   voya_20140801
3 voya_20140801_2.SID voya_20140801_2
> listfiles <- list.files (copy_from)
> listfiles
 [1] "voya_20140710.SID"         "voya_20140710.xml"         "voya_20140721.SID"         "voya_20140721.SID.aux.xml" "voya_20140721.xml"         "voya_20140801.SID"        
 [7] "voya_20140801.SID.aux.xml" "voya_20140801.xml"         "voya_20140801_2.SID"       "voya_20140801_2.xml"
```

Here is the dataframe identifying the files I wanted copied...

```
index <- structure(list(filename = c("voya_20140721.SID", "voya_20140801.SID", 
"voya_20140801_2.SID"), name = c("voya_20140721", "voya_20140801", 
"voya_20140801_2")), .Names = c("filename", "name"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

-cherrytree

Comment: I don't understand.  Why not just run `Map(file.copy, copy_from_vec, copy_to_vec)`.  having to read in another file just to find out which files you want to copy is a bit of a waste of effort.

Comment: I think you might not understand..I only want to copy select files, not all of them. For example, there may be 400 files but I only want 10 of them copied.